# Need to create a new page when the table exceeds to next page in apache poi word

Tags: apache-poi, apache-poi-4

Need to create a new page when the table exceeds to next page in apache poi

Comment: Generally Microsoft Word is pretty good about auto-flowing things onto new pages, what makes you think this built-in functionality isn't enough?

Comment: I have another table just below the second table .

Comment: So when the first table overflow the second table should be coming to next page . I am designing my page in apache POI word

Comment: document.createParagraph().createRun().addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);  this can fix the issue